# Unable to find/build a commenting system similar as at Djangobook

Tags: django, comments

I want to open-source my notes similarly as at [DjangoBook](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter01/).
I have not found any similar open-source system as at the website.
I am particularly interested in the vertical commenting system.

This suggests me that I need to build one by myself for open-source.

**How would you build a similar commenting system as at the website?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each paragraph (`<p>`) in the document has an ID (`cn0, cn1,` etc.) and a class (`cn`). This is the only part of the comment system rendered near the text. Also on the page is the `div` that acts as the popup, which also contains the comment form.

The rest is done with Javascript. When the page is loaded, they send an AJAX request back to get the number and location of all the comments in the document. It looks like:

```
[[0,4],[3,2],...]
```

With this, it adds a `div` in the margin with the speech bubble and number of comments on that line.

When you click on the bubbles, another AJAX request is initiated to get the comments for that bubble. In this case, they send down the actual HTML to be rendered instead of a JSON object like before.

On the backend (this is all conjecture now) they're tying each set of comments to a document and a location in that document (this allows them to show all comments for a document at once). I would probably use the built-in comments app to do this, and either package both items into one foreign key, by creating a model to link the document and location, or by subclassing the Comment model itself.

Hope this gets you in the right direction. You can probably learn more by looking at [their Javascript](http://new-media.djangobook.com/djangobook.js), <s>but it's been minified, so it's a little hard to read</s>(UPDATE: found unminified js). They're building on YUI, but the code is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @tghw: Do you know how to make the js -file readable effectively. I run in Vim's visual mode "=" for indendation, but I am not happy with the result.

Comment: No, but I did find the URL of the full, unminified JS. I've updated the link above.

Comment: @tghw: Thank you for the updates! --- Which tool did you use to find out the new link? --- I did not find the newest .js -file by Firefug.

Comment: Just guessed, the original file was djangobook-all-min.js, so i tried djangobook-all.js, nothing there, but djangobook.js did it.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested by Wooki. It's a collaborative writing platform, 100% open source and free. It was based on Django Book system.

Take a look : http://wookicentral.com

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago (2 years'ish) someone created a Django project to mimic the DjangoBook called [Open Book Platform](http://code.google.com/p/openbookplatform/).

It has been dormant for a long time and might not even work properly on Django 0.96 let alone 1.0.x.  However, when I just visited to get the URL I notice there's been some activity in the last month.

Comment: @Van Gale: Thank you for the link and the piece of history! --- I did not know that Django is rather a "copy" of another platform. --- Do you know whether the developers are the same in Django and Open Book Platform? --- It seems that Open Book Platform uses the word Django often. This suggests me that they are the same developers. --- However, the Chinese in Open Book Platform suggests that there have been many developers, since one European seems to be a creator of Django.

Comment: err, Open Book Platform is a project that was developed using an older version of Django.  It's a project, using Django, to mimic how DjangoBook worked.  Sorry for not being clear.  You could probably get it running on current version of Django with a little work.  And yes, it looks like the new maintainers of the project are Chinese, no idea what their plans are.

Answer (score 1):

Remark box is built on the same principles as the DjangoBook comment system, its a free service for small sites.

And unlike the projects or plug-ins others have mentioned on this thread, it can be used on any HTML page, integration is just a few JavaScript lines.

Their front page has a live demo http://www.remarkbox.com/

Comment: Site's dead -- suggesting deletion

Comment: @benjaoming: Seems to load for me. It's source-only Markdown for some reason, but that's theoretically a valid choice....

Answer (score 1):

There's a free, and fully supported, Django package that we built to have the same functionality as the Django Book site.

http://ucomment.org

That codebase is used on several publicly-available websites, such at http://connectmv.com/tutorials

We do our best to maintain this package: installation can take some time - which is expected, given what the software is doing.  Please give it a try and send us your feedback via the commenting feature on the http://ucomment.org site.

Kevin

Comment: where are you Kevin? I'm trying to locate you to share some thoughts/issues/perhaps contributions on ucomment... I've forked your repository at bitbucket, perhaps you are interested on looking at my pull-requests?

Comment: site is dead -- suggesting to remove answer

Answer (score 0):

I thought the DjangoBook site was built with Django, which would seem to imply it uses the [Django comments framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/).

UPDATE: There's a note [here](http://djangobook.com/about/comments/) which attributes a lot of the code for the comment system to [Jack Slocum](http://jackslocum.com/blog/). The link on the DjangoBook page is dead, so I couldn't find any additional info, but it *may* be that the code referred to is for the YUI/AJAX pieces that make the contextual commenting possible.

Comment: @Harper: You mean that the Django has a built-in commenting system similar as at DjangoBook?

Comment: It has a built in comment system, but it doesn't do the inline comments like DjangoBook does.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using WordPress with [CommentPress](http://www.futureofthebook.org/commentpress/) plugin that is adding similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno why I fall in this post again, but this is right now done by a lot of site I think. A nice implementation is: https://github.com/aroc/side-comments/